# Als ob + Indikativ

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, grammatical-mood

Einige Muttersprachler sagen:

**Er tut so, als ob er Witze macht**

Ich frage mich, ob der Satz entweder grammatikalisch richtig oder akzeptabel ist. Am College wurde mir beigebracht, dass man den Ausdruck mit dem **Konjunktiv**
benutzt.

Comment: Die Lehrer wollten eben, daß ihr den Konjunktiv trainiert. Deshalb haben sie es unterlassen zu erwähnen, daß der Indikativ ebenfalls möglich ist.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich würde der Vollständigkeit halber den Beispielsatz noch mit Konjunktiv aufnehmen. Und die Frage so formulieren, dass "wie anderen" gefragt werden.

Answer (score 4):

Jede lebende Sprache verändert sich ständig. Wäre das nicht der Fall, würden wir noch immer Althochdeutsch oder Urindoeuropäisch sprechen. Dieser Wandel erfolgt nur sehr selten so abrupt, dass man ihn wahrnimmt. Tatsächlich besteht diese Veränderung im überwiegenden Maße so langsam und schleichend vonstatten, dass man sie kaum merkt. Zu allen Zeiten haben ältere Menschen den Verfall der Sprache bemängelt. In Wahrheit haben sie nur bemerkt, dass die Sprache, die sie vor einem Dreiviertel Jahrhundert als Kind gelernt haben, durch eine modernere Variante verdrängt wurde.

Und dann gibt es noch den Spracherwerb, also das Erlernen einer Sprache. Wenn man als Kind die Sprache seiner Mitmenschen lernt, paukt man keine Vokabeln und lernt keine Grammatikregeln. Man lernt die Muttersprache nicht als explizites Wissen, sondern implizit, so wie man Gehen oder Radfahren lernt. Man versucht es und lernt durch Nachahmung, Versuch und Irrtum. Man kann danach aber das Gelernte nur sehr schwer in Worten wiedergeben.

Wenn man eine Sprache als Fremdsprache lernt, lernt man diese Sprache vor allem zu Beginn explizit. Das heißt, man lern Regeln und versucht, diese Regeln dann umzusetzen. Das ist eine andere Art des Lernens. Vor allem erfordert dieser explizite Wissenserwerb, dass es fertig ausformulierte Regeln gibt. Und da kommen Fachleute ins Spiel, die den Muttersprachlern zuhören und lesen was sie geschrieben haben. Sie analysieren diese Sprache und leiten daraus Regeln ab, die sie dann in Bücher schreiben und publizieren.

Das ist gut, richtig und wichtig, denn es dient zum einen der Normierung der Sprache und bewirkt im Fall der deutschen Sprache, dass sich jemand aus einem Dorf in den Alpen mit jemanden unterhalten kann, der auf den friesischen Inseln aufgewachsen ist. Und solche Regeln sind sehr hilfreich für Leute, die eine Fremdsprache erlernen. Denn, wie schon erwähnt, erfolgt der Erwerb einer Fremdsprache vor allem am Beginn auf explizitem Wege.

Nun macht aber die stetige Veränderung einer lebenden Sprache jenen Leuten Probleme, die die Regeln aufschreiben. Denn die Regeln verändern sich fortwährend. Und während sich eine Regel verändert, ist nicht klar, ob die gerade festgestellte Abweichung zwischen der ausformulierten Regel und dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch eine kurzfristige und regional beschränkte Modeerscheinung ist, oder ob sich die Abweichung zur neuen Norm entwickeln wird.

Daher können die Regeln überhaupt nicht den aktuellen Status einer Sprache wiedergeben. Sie sind immer nur ein mehr oder weniger guter Versuch, ein Idealbild der Sprache wiederzugeben, und sie hinken dem aktuellen Status auch immer um mehrere Jahrzehnte hinterher. Daher gibt es in jeder lebenden Sprache immer Abweichungen zwischen der in Lehrbüchern wiedergegebenen Beschreibung der Sprache und dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch.

Aber was bedeutet das für den, der eine fremde Sprache lernen will?

Es bedeutete, dann man gerade am Beginn der Erwerbs der neuen Sprache darauf vertrauen sollte, dass die Bücher und die Lehrer recht haben. Man sollte das lernen, was einem beigebracht wird, denn das ist auf jeden Fall richtig. (Gelegentliche Irrtümer klären sich meist rasch auf.) Aber einer gewissen Stufe muss man aber vom expliziten Lernen zum impliziten Lernen übergehen, mann muss die Sprache also so weiterlernen, wie es Kleinkinder machen: durch ständigen Gebrauch.

Irgendwann muss man einfach zuhören und sprechen sowie lesen und schreiben, und darf dabei nicht immer die gelernten Regeln rezitieren, sondern muss darauf vertrauen, dass die Muttersprachler ihre eigene Sprache richtig verwenden. Denn weder die Lehrer noch die festgeschriebenen Regeln in Büchern definieren eine Sprache, sondern der tatsächliche Gebrauch der Sprache durch die Gemeinschaft der Muttersprachler definiert eine Sprache. Und wenn man mal feststellt, dass das, was die Muttersprachler im Alltag machen anders ist als das, was man aus den Büchern gelernt hat, dann kann es auch durchaus sein, dass beides richtig ist.

Im Zweifel gilt: Wenn man etwas schreibt, sollte man die Regeln aus den Büchern anwenden. Wenn man spricht, sollte man wie die Muttersprachler sprechen.